# GridView onDataBinding

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

i have a gridview that uses template where in that template i have two buttons:
here is my code:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gvtransaction" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="60%" OnDataBinding="gvtransaction_DataBinding">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Consumer">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblfirstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbllastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Amount") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcurrencyID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrencyID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcurrencyname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrencyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateCreated">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbldatecreated" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateCreated") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Select" OnClick="btnApprove_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" CommandName="Select" OnClick="btnReject_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

what i want to happen is, when the page loads and it sees that the status is not Pending, the buttons should not be visible otherwise the buttons are visible.

help anyone.?

Comment: have you set the logic on gvtransaction_DataBinding ?

Comment: not yet..no clue on how to start..

Comment: you may use `RowDataBound` event of grid view aw well.

Comment: here is a good example for you [Gridview, hide button on RowDataBound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598376/gridview-hide-button-on-rowdatabound)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with You,I develop it on vb.net, on your `gvtransaction_DataBinding` code behind add code something like this :

```
 'Get The Data Row'
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            'Get Label Status Value'
            Dim lblstatus As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblstatus"), Label)
            
            'Get Button Items'
            Dim btnapprove As Button= DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("btnApprove"), Button)
            Dim btnReject As Button= DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("btnReject"), Button)
            
            If lblstatus.Text = "Pending" Then
                btnapprove.Visible = true
                 btnReject.visible = true
            Else
               btnapprove.Visible = false
                 btnReject.visible = false
            End If
        End If
```

glad if its what You're looking for .

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you want to only show hide the button's based on condition and more performance,then you have to show hide button on Client side rather than go to server side and iterate `RowDataBound` Event. In my opinion you have to use Client code like that.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Visible='<%# Bind("Status") %> =="Pending" ? True:False'
                    Text="Approve" CommandName="Select" OnClick="btnApprove_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Visible='<%# Bind("Status") %> =="Pending" ? True:False'
                    Text="Reject" CommandName="Select" OnClick="btnReject_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am not saying the RowDataBound Event is not achieved your goal,but yes its hit the performance.

Hope it helps you.